# Why is $\det(I+MM^T) = \det(I+M^TM)$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a real valued $m$ by $n$ matrix $M$ with $m<n$, why is the following true?

$$\det(I+MM^T) = \det(I+M^TM)\;?$$

To me this seems counter-intuitive as $\det(M^TM) = 0$.

Comment: Why is det$(M^TM) = 0$?

Comment: because $MM^T$ and $M^TM$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues ...

Comment: @MichaelHarrison My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @user251257 That's very interesting. How do we know that?

Comment: @Lembik: singular value decomposition

Comment: @Théophile Yes it does.

Comment: @MichaelHarrison No I was actually right. Notice that $m< n$ so $\det(M^TM)  = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of [Sylvester's determinant law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity) which states that for an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and an $n\times m$ matrix $B$, $\operatorname{det}(I_m + AB) = \operatorname{det}(I_n + BA)$. In your case, $A = M$ and $B = M^T$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why adding the identity makes such a difference? It certainly isn't true without this addition.

Comment: @Lembik One explanation is this.  It's _almost_ true.  Recall that if $m=n$, it's certainly true that $\det(MM^T)=\det(M^TM)$.  With $m<n$, it is still true if $M$ is rank deficient, since both $MM^T$ and $M^TM$ are singular.  It fails for $m<n$ only when $M$ is full-rank, as $M^TM$ is necessarily singular while $MM^T$ is not.  However as user251257 pointed out, they still have the same non-zero eigenvalues.  Now, recall that adding an identity matrix increments each eigenvalue by 1, and that the determinant is the product of all eigenvalues.  It follows that both products equal.

Answer (score 0):

using the SVD decomposition : $M = U S V^*, M^* = V S^* U^*$,

$$I + M M^* = U(SS^* +I)U^*, \qquad I + M^* M =  V (S S^* +I) V^*$$

and $det(V A) = det(A) = det(A V)$ for any unitary matrix $V$, hence :

$$det(I+MM^* ) = det(I+M^* M) = det(I+S S^* )$$

if $M$ is real, then $M^* = M^T$ and you get what you asked.

Comment: If you use a skinny SVD, then you can't assume $UU^*=I$. I you use a full SVD, then one of the $SS^*$ should be $S^*S$.

Comment: yes you are right, edit it if you'd like

Comment: then you should explain, why the result remains unchanged.

Comment: ok, with $M_{z(k)}$ denoting the zero padding of $M$ such that it becomes a $k \times k$ matrix, $det(I_m + M M^T) = det(I_n +M_{z(n)} M_{z(n)}^T)$, this is quite obvious since $M_{z(n)} M_{z(n)}^T = (M  M^T)_{z(n)}$

Comment: you should edit your answer.

Comment: no it's ok, do it if you'd ilke, otherwise the comments are enough